# Shorter way to access property of attribute, without needing to access it twice

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
foreach (var cmd in subcommands.OrderBy(s =>
    (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(s.Module.ModuleType, typeof(BotCategoryAttribute)) as BotCategoryAttribute)?.Name))
{
    var module = (BotCategoryAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(cmd.Module.ModuleType, typeof(BotCategoryAttribute));
    if (module != null)
    {
        if (!modules.ContainsKey(module.Name))
        {
            modules[module.Name] = new List<Command>();
        }

        modules[module.Name].Add(cmd);
    }
}
```

I have the following code in which I order subcommand alphabetically based `Name` property of the `BotCategoryAttribute`.

Later in the code, I access the `Name` property again, is there a shorter way to accomplish this? I feel like I'm doing twice almost the same thing.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BotCategoryAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BotCategoryAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a select first that includes the name and the command. then order by the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `Select` first that includes the name and the command. Then order by the `Name`.

From there it is just a matter of accessing the member as needed.

```
var orderedList = subcommands.Select(s => new { 
    SubCommand = s,
    Name = (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(s.Module.ModuleType, typeof(BotCategoryAttribute)) as BotCategoryAttribute)?.Name
}).OrderBy(s => s.Name);

foreach (var cmd in orderedList) {
    string moduleName = cmd.Name;
    if (moduleName != null) {
        if (!modules.ContainsKey(moduleName)) {
            modules[moduleName] = new List<Command>();
        }    
        modules[moduleName].Add(cmd.SubCommand);
    }
}
```